# Can you set inode quotas in ZFS?

Tags: solaris, zfs

I figured out how to set block quotas in ZFS from the [documentation on oracle's site](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/gazvb/index.html).

I didn't see if / how to setup a quota on how many inodes a user gets, though.  I realize that there may not be restrictions on how many inodes a ZFS filesystem has, but when my users create a directory tree 10,000 directories deep each with 300 files, it is kind of a pain in the butt to deal with.

Bonus points if you can set it in the oracle storage appliance...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Short Answer

No

#### Long Answer

Quoting from ["Chapter 1 Oracle Solaris ZFS File System (Introduction)"](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/6n7ht6qr5/index.html#6n7ht6qtm):

> All metadata is allocated dynamically, so no need exists to preallocate inodes or otherwise limit the scalability of the file system when it is first created.
>
> ...no limit exists on the number of file systems or the number of files that can be contained within a file system.

There was also a discussion of this same issue back in 2009 on the [zfs-discuss](http://www.mail-archive.com/zfs-discuss@opensolaris.org/) mailing list.

> [Re: [zfs-discuss] ZFS directory and file quota](http://www.mail-archive.com/zfs-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg31312.html)
>
> > I can not find any instructions on how to set the file quota (i.e. maximum number of files per filesystem/directory) or directory quota (maximum size that files in particular directory can consume) in ZFS.
>
> That is because it doesn't exist.

Here's another good quote from mailing list in August 2010:

> [Re: [zfs-discuss] File system ownership details of ZFS file system.](http://www.mail-archive.com/zfs-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg41432.html)
>
> ZFS does not have a fixed number of inodes, so there is no way to calculate a limit, per se.  ZFS uses space for metadata, so as long as you have available space, you can use it for metadata.

In [another thread in 2010](http://www.mail-archive.com/zfs-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg43752.html) there was a discussion on how to calculate the number of inodes for a ZFS filesystem based on the total space (there's also a helpful script provided).

Quoting [one of the replies](http://www.mail-archive.com/zfs-discuss@opensolaris.org/msg43751.html):

> In ZFS, you will run out of inodes at the same time as you run out of space.

#### Possible Solution

You can, however, enforce user-level inode quotas by using UFS filesystems on ZFS zvols.

- UFS zvols

  - [Fun with zvols - UFS on a zvol](https://blogs.oracle.com/scottdickson/entry/fun_with_zvols_-_ufs)
  - [Taking UFS new places safely with ZFS zvols](https://blogs.oracle.com/pgdh/entry/taking_ufs_new_places_safely)
- UFS quotas

  - [Chapter 7 Managing UFS Quotas (Tasks)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/817-0403/sysresquotas-97946/index.html)

Comment: That's too bad.  I work in an environment with hundreds of thousands of users each with unique UIDs and simply running find ~homedir | wc -l would take a couple months.  If I had quotas it would be simpler to track these users down.  As it is, I just wait until a user with 20gajillion files causes trouble for some of our other systems (malware scanning, backups, etc).  Thanks!

Comment: This is an interesting (and old) question. It makes me curious whether metadata usage counts toward quotas. If it does, that could give an implicit inode max for a user.

Comment: I just noticed in [ZoL 0.7.13 manual](https://zfsonlinux.org/manpages/0.7.13/man8/zfs.8.html) there is a `userobjused` property and `userobjquota` which might be the kind of thing @chris is looking for. Obviously this is a different ZFS implementation but might be worth revisiting what Solaris ZFS / Oracle Linux ZFS does.